# Zero still in list after deletion (Python)

Tags: python, list

I have a list below *Prob* and I when I try to remove 0 or remove 0.0 it sometimes doesn't remove from the list or there is 'another version' of 0 still in the list. How can I make sure that all 'flavors' of zero are removed from the list since it is impossible to list out all possible decimal increments for zero?

```
 x = [0.0,
 0.0,
 0,
 0.0009765625,
 0.0003255208333333333,
 0.0021158854166666665,
 0.005045572916666667,
 0.013020833333333334,
 0.019856770833333332,
 0.0107421875,
 0.004557291666666667,
 0.000]
    
if 0 in probability_perpoint:
    probability_perpoint.remove(0)
if 0.0 in probability_perpoint:
    probability_perpoint.remove(0.0)

`print(x)` # still prints 0's!
```

Comment: ```remove``` removes only the **first** occurence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply do this way with `list comprehension`,

```
x = [0.0,0.0,0,0.0009765625,0.0003255208333333333,0.0021158854166666665,0.005045572916666667,0.013020833333333334,0.019856770833333332,0.0107421875,0.004557291666666667,0.000]
x = [i for i in x if i != 0]
print(x)
```

**Demo:** https://rextester.com/NAVN53491

Another way with `remove()` and `while`

```
x = [0.0,0.0,0,0.0009765625,0.0003255208333333333,0.0021158854166666665,0.005045572916666667,0.013020833333333334,0.019856770833333332,0.0107421875,0.004557291666666667,0.000]
try:
    while True:
        x.remove(0)
except ValueError:
    pass
 
print(x)
```

**Demo:** https://rextester.com/YTXM11780

Answer (score 2):

`list.remove` only removes the first occurrence, so you should build the list from scratch as repeated removals are expensive. Moreover, if these are results of some calculation and subject to rounding errors you might want to look at `math.isclose`:

```
import math

x[:] = [e for e in x if not math.isclose(e, 0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Python's **filter-function** is perfect for this problem.
You can specify your filter criteria in form of an **anonymous lambda function** as first argument and the list you would like to filter through as second argument.

```
x = [0.0,
 0.0,
 0,
 0.0009765625,
 0.0003255208333333333,
 0.0021158854166666665,
 0.005045572916666667,
 0.013020833333333334,
 0.019856770833333332,
 0.0107421875,
 0.004557291666666667,
 0.000]
    
result = list(filter(lambda n: n!=0, x))

print(result)
```

beware that you have to **convert the result into a list**